# Spring validation by @valid in service layer

Tags: spring, validation, annotations

My data format is:  data[model][field]
So, in control layer i am processing the object of my desire class and passing object to service layer. Now i want to put (@Valid Designation desg) in service layer function. But it's not working.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Designation/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Object saveDesignation(@PathVariable String role, @ModelAttribute Designation desg, BindingResult result,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    desg.setName(request.getParameter("data[designation][name]"));
    return desgService.insert(desg, result, request, role, Designation.class);
}
```

Service Layer:

```
public Object insert(@Valid Designation desg, BindingResult result,  String role, Class clazz) {
              ...............
}
```

Servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="net.divineIt.titas.controllers" /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="net.divineIt.titas.services" />
```

Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: `@Valid` will, by default, only work on controller methods not on methods in other componts. For that you would need to do additional configuration and it will only work with hibernate validator. You would need to add the `MethodValidationInterceptor` and the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` to have the interceptor registered. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationInterceptor.html.

Comment: Thank you @Denim... i will go through this